# How to make footer elements be same width with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a footer for my project which has two images... each one of them is stuck to a particular corner. The lower left corner is the Division logo (system_footer_left); while the lower right corner is the Brand Logo (system_footer_right). What I would like to do is to have the size of the section to be the same as the width, even if the widths of the images are not the same.

How can I make this happen?

In my current project design, the left logo is about half the width of the right logo.

I am rusty with CSS, I have not been able to find any answers online. I did not want to set the width as a fixed percentage as I would like to have it be dynamic, so that if we change brand assets (logos) it will just "plug and play".

```css
#system_footer {
  padding: 5 5 0 5;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(5, 51, 107, .75);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#system_footer_center {
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFD700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FF8C00;
}

#system_footer_right {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: right;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 3px outset rgba(208, 207, 204, .5);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#system_footer_right:hover {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: right;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 4px outset rgba(231, 231, 229, 1);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#system_footer_left {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 3px outset rgba(208, 207, 204, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#system_footer_left:hover {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 4px outset rgba(231, 231, 229, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.cny-logo-sm {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 35px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: calc(12px + (16 - 12) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1000 - 300)));
  }
}


/* WITHOUT THE BLOCK BELOW, THE FONT WOULD CONTINUE TO GROW */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='system_footer'>
  <div id='system_footer_left'>
    <img src='../resources/logo/b_white_trans.png' alt='(Decorative) ' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_right'>
    <img src='.../resources/logo/cny.png' alt='CNY (Logo)' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_center'>
    <p>For technical support, please contact XXXX at <a href='mailto:DONTEMAIL@MY.BRAND.COM?subject=MCR System'>XXX@XXXX.XXX</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the left and right footer element frames to be the same width dynamically.

Comment: are you sayong that images shold take the full width

Comment: ok still i dont clear your question. Could you please explain bit more

Comment: @NipunTharuksha No. the image size is being managed by css class <code>.cny-logo-sm{ width:auto;  max-height:35px; object-fit: scale-down; } </code> what I would like to do is make the segments be equal width, while maintaining the center area for system messages (i.e. tech support link)

Comment: @psycoperl for what footer is fixed to bottom ?

Comment: @IvanKaraman I assume you are asking why the footer is fixed to the bottom? The footer includes branding and also allows an easy way to display information such as technical support or other notices such as may be dictated.  The primary use of the footer is to make sure that the two logos are displayed always on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. You can't by CSS set the same width for 2 elements based on their content, you can set the width in percent or in other relative units for both containers and align content inside. I have updated hover effects and sizes because it looks bad when content jumps. I remove duplicated CSS, you have same styles on the left and the right blocks. Images keep aspect ratio, updated styles. Sorry for my bad English.

```css
.cny-logo-sm {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 35px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
#system_footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 5px 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(5, 51, 107, .75);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#system_footer_center {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFD700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FF8C00;
}
#system_footer_right {
  order: 3;
}
#system_footer_left,
#system_footer_right {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  /*max-width: 30%;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 3px outset rgba(208, 207, 204, .5);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
#system_footer_left:hover,
#system_footer_right:hover {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  max-width: 30%;
  border: 4px outset rgba(231, 231, 229, 1);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: calc(12px + (16 - 12) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1000 - 300)));
  }
}

/* WITHOUT THE BLOCK BELOW, THE FONT WOULD CONTINUE TO GROW */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='system_footer'>
  <div id='system_footer_left'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x30' alt='(Decorative) ' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_right'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/270x270' alt='CNY (Logo)' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_center'>
    <p>For technical support, please contact XXXX at <a href='mailto:DONTEMAIL@MY.BRAND.COM?subject=MCR System'>XXX@XXXX.XXX</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. However, the system_footer_left and system_footer_right had similar but not identical hover effects and styles as they were styled differently, with the lighter borders and drop shadow always facing the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand you request but I think that this is what you are needing

```
#system_footer_left img,
#system_footer_right img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```css
#system_footer {
  padding: 5 5 0 5;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(5, 51, 107, .75);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#system_footer_center {
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFD700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FF8C00;
}

#system_footer_right {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: right;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 3px outset rgba(208, 207, 204, .5);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#system_footer_right:hover {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: right;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 4px outset rgba(231, 231, 229, 1);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#system_footer_left {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 3px outset rgba(208, 207, 204, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
#system_footer_left img,
#system_footer_right img{
width:100%;
}
#system_footer_left:hover {
  background: rgb(170, 213, 255);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(170, 213, 255, 0.5) 8%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 29%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 0.6362920168067228) 67%, rgba(170, 213, 255, 1) 100%, rgba(5, 51, 107, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#aad5ff", endColorstr="#05336b", GradientType=1);
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 4px outset rgba(231, 231, 229, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 1px -0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.cny-logo-sm {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 35px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: calc(12px + (16 - 12) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1000 - 300)));
  }
}


/* WITHOUT THE BLOCK BELOW, THE FONT WOULD CONTINUE TO GROW */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #system_footer_center {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='system_footer'>
  <div id='system_footer_left'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/500x60?text=Decorative' alt='(Decorative) ' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_right'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/250?text=logo' alt='CNY (Logo)' class='cny-logo-sm'>
  </div>
  <div id='system_footer_center'>
    <p>For technical support, please contact XXXX at <a href='mailto:DONTEMAIL@MY.BRAND.COM?subject=MCR System'>XXX@XXXX.XXX</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you could use grid:

https://codepen.io/cschloegel/pen/wVzKZo

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-left"></div>
    <div class="footer-center"></div>
    <div class="footer-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  background-color:lightgrey;
  height:100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "content content content" "footer footer footer";
}

.header { 
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content { grid-area: content; }

.footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "footer-left footer-center footer-right";
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color:grey;
}

.footer-left { 
  grid-area: footer-left;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color:darkgrey;
}

.footer-center { grid-area: footer-center; }

.footer-right { grid-area: footer-right;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color:darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain Grid? I am not sure I am following.

Comment: Added a pen link to my answer so that you can visualize it.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful... will investigate and see if I can adapt to my current design which I have many parts built on using W3-CSS.